# How to identify cloudbuild child tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build, gcloud, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a CloudBuild `cloudbuild.yaml` file which defines a task to export a GCE Image to a Bucket in `.vmdk` format.

```sh
    gcloud compute images export \
    --image=$IMAGE_NAME \
    --destination-uri=$DESTINATION_BUCKET/$VMDK_NAME \
    --export-format=vmdk \
    --network=$NETWORK \
    --subnet=$SUBNET \
    --project=$PROJECT_ID \
    --async
```

The `gcloud compute images export` is working fine; the command triggers a child CloudBuild to convert and to upload to gcs.

There are no fields in the new build that identifies the "parent" caller, these fields are empty:
`Provider`, `Source`, `Ref Commit`, `Trigger Id`, `Trigger Type`, `Trigger Name`, `Trigger Description`

How can I identify these child process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

I think you may be unable to do this (see Hack below) because there's no user-definable metadata that you can pass from the parent Cloud Build task through the `gcloud compute images export ...` to the child Cloud Build task.

> **Hack** I've not tried this! It may (!?) be possible to inject a trace token from Cloud Build into the step that invokes `gcloud compute images export` command using the [`--trace-token`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--trace-token) flag. You could try (I've not tried this) setting this flag on `gcloud compute images export ... --trace-token=${SOMETHING}` perhaps using the value of the parent's Cloud Build ID? This **should** be passed through subsequent API calls and hopefully at least reaches as far the child Cloud Build.

I think it's a useful feature request to be able to pass arbitrary metadata (labels?) through Cloud SDK commands. You should consider submitting a request to Google's [Issue Tracker for Cloud SDK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143)